# How to set text with ending .... on UILabel

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am setting the `UILabel` text as below

```
myLabel.text = name;
```

What I would like to ask is if the text goes longer I want to show like below

```
stackoverflowuserhere.........
```

How can I done it...

Thanks for any help

Comment: if you have set the UILabel using IB, try deselecting the Adjust to Fix option available for UILabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your text to truncate at 20 characters you have to do it manually.

```
NSString *truncatedName = name;
if ([truncatedName length] > 20)
    truncatedName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [truncatedName substringToIndex:20]];
myLabel.text = truncatedName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the line break mode e.g.

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation
```

Have a look @ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UILineBreakMode for the other ways to handle text that is too long.

Comment: I don't think you can set the number of characters to display for the ... one of the reasons being that not all characters are the same width! By default the UILabel will put as many characters as it can inside it's bounding box. You could try changing the size of the label to change how many characters it can fit. If you need to fit more characters in you can set the font to something smaller.